# Extremely slow webkit animation since update

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, animation, webkit

I have a slider which is now completely unusable in the latest versions of chrome and safari, older versions show it fine. While developing it I tested chrome, firefox and IE, They all worked fine (except some style issues in the older ie's but the animation was fine).

Minimal test case of it here
http://www.thetrainingconcept.co.uk/error.htm

The javascript can be found here
http://assets.thetrainingconcept.co.uk/www/js/plugins/jquery.feature-slide.js?v=1.0.0

I can not figure this one out at all, there are no js errors, I profiled it and that looks ok. I tried making a simple test case to profile it but got the exact same behavior.

I really hope someone has some idea of what's going wrong here.

***Edit:*** I'll also note that I've searched high and low, read many "slow animations in chrome" issues, none of which have been any help. Remember, this worked absolutely fine until a recent update affecting chrome and safari. The version of chrome I'm using is Version 23.0.1271.97 m, if you have an older version it may appear correctly.

Comment: i am on windows8 chrome version Version 23.0.1271.97 m. all working fine no issues with the animation.

Comment: Are you speaking about top animation "Develop yourself"? Because here on windows7 works the same on chrome and firefox. Maybe reset your chrome's cache.

Comment: Can't you make a minimal example demonstrating the problem ?

Comment: Here is the slider with everything else removed, you can click on the left and right bits. http://www.thetrainingconcept.co.uk/error.htm

Comment: Also this has been verified as broken on multiple machines running windows, and os x, so clearing my cache isn't going to sort it :( Removing everything else on the page seems to help the issue, but the frame rate of the animation is still god awful.

Comment: there is a bug in firefox, a big white space before the crepe, then if you click on it, a 404; otherwise i've experienced myself some weird/unpredictable behaviour on chrome while combining jquery & css transition but no solution or understanding yet

Comment: @mikakun the site is not officially live so we are aware of a few 404's etc, the big white space is were the client has created a panel but not filled it with an article, but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @evo i see it now, really weird animation in chrome

Comment: I forgot I already had a stackoverflow account, so signed into this one now. I've made progress, removing animate.css from the page sorts out the animation. Will investigate more and post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. The answer, in my opinion, is not obvious, if it is to someone else, could they explain it to me please?

So, animate.css applies `-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;` to the body tag. For some reason, this caused all the problems I've faced with the javascript animation being awful. Luckily I'm not using the 3D animations from that library, so I can remove it and solve my issue.

Now, I'm not sure if this is a bug in webkit or a bug in animate.css, I'm leaning towards it being a problem with webkit as I don't understand why that property should cause the slowdowns it did to none css animations.

http://daneden.me/animate/ - the css animation library
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/ - more explanation about the backface-visibility property